# Overlapping AJAX requests in a single function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is foo below safe if it is called twice in quick succession such that the second call occurs before the first response is received ? If it is safe could you please explain the mechanism behind how the correct "param" value gets matched to the correct "xmlHttp" response ?

```
function foo (param)
{
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpRequestObject();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            // do something involving param and xmlHttp.responseXML
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "GetAsyncData.ashx", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091810/ajax-not-working-in-loop/15092127#15092127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var xmlHttp` is bound to the function `foo` scope. Each time the function is called, a new `xmlHttp` is set. For function parameters, the same happens. Parameters are also bound to the function scope the same way as `var xmlHttp` is. So, in this case, each time the function is called, the `param` and the `xmlHttp` are both variables bound to the same scope, and this is the reason why each `param` is going to be matched to the correct `xmlHttp` response.

For more insight, read about javascript closures.

Answer (score 0):

`var` scopes a variable to a function. Each call to that function will create a new variable with that name.